# Best way to get the values of members of a private instance variable container

Tags: c++, opencv, return, instance, private-members

I'm quite newbie with c++, and I'm having some trouble figuring out what is the best way to do this.

I've implemented a class, let's call it imageContainer, which has a private vector of images and methods to fill this vector with images. Suppose now, I have another class that have a private imageContainer, and now, after correctly initializing this imageContainer (reading the images I want it to contain) I need to process its images. Keep in mind that my processing won't change the base images, only calculate some things using them. What would be the best, most secure way of getting those images, without copying them? I want to avoid copying them because I might have many, big images, which would make the process of copying pretty slow.

Oh, and the images I'm reading are all of openCV's Mat type. The "=" operator on Mat doesn't make a copy of the Mat, it only share the data, which makes me think the best way to get the images would be:

```c++
Mat imageContainer::getImage(size_t index)
{
    return vectorOfImages[index];
}
```

but I'm not really sure about that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no usage of operator =, only copy c-tor...

Comment: It is the only way you should return private members. Else you would not need to make them private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a reference to avoid a copy and make it const to disallow modification:

```
const Mat& imageContainer::getImage(size_t index) const
{
  return vectorOfImages[index];
}
```